# MAUI: Unable to share ResourceDictionaries between two SDK-style projects

Tags: c#, xaml, sdk, resourcedictionary, maui

I have two SDK-style MAUI projects, let's say Project1 and Project2. Project2 has following structure:

```
Project2.sln
    |
    - Resources
        |
        - Colors.xaml
```

Colors.xaml has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    x:Class="Project2.Resources.Colors">

    <Color x:Key="TestColor">#512BD4</Color>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The goal is to use `TestColor` in Project1, maybe later in Project3, Project4, and so on. As long as [standard WPF-like XAML notation does not work in MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4398), we have to include this file as following:

Project1/App.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:Project2.Resources;assembly=Project2"
             x:Class="Project1.App">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <resources:Colors />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

This one at least can compile without errors, but that does not work. When i am trying to use new static resource in some king of view, like this:

Project1/MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TestColor}" />
```

It throws a runtime error `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: 'Position XX:XX. StaticResource not found for key TestColor'` and IntelliSense having no clue about TestColor so. The question is: how do i need to properly link my external ResourceDictionary in other projects using MAUI?

Comment: Have you tried the syntax from [StephaneDelcroix's comment](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4398#issuecomment-1025514669)?  `<ResourceDictionary Source="path/to/rd.xaml;assembly=otherAssembly">`.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yeah that's not working too.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: During app startup, manually copy all the entries in the dll's resourcedictionary into `Application.Current.Resources`.
In shared `App.xaml.cs`:

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // TODO: Code to get dll's resourcedictionary.
    ResourceDictionary rd1 = ...;   // Project2.Resources?

    // Copy all entries into app's Resources.
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in rd1)
    {
        Application.Current.Resources[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
    }

    MainPage = new AppShell();  // Or whatever you have here.
}
```

---

TODO: Code to get dll's resourcedictionary.

I haven't worked with dll's in Maui, so not certain the code you need for this step.